# Printing formatted tuple values

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

This may be the simplest of questions. But I tried to print the individual values of the tuple in the following manner.

```
mytuple=('new','lets python','python 2.7')

>>> print "%{0} experience, %{1} with %{2} " %mytuple
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    print "%{0} experience, %{1} with %{2} " %mytuple
ValueError: unsupported format character '{' (0x7b) at index 1
```

I want to print the output to be like the following.

```
"new experience, lets python with python 2.7"
```

I don't remember where it was it done. Is it called unpacking tuple values, printing formatted tuples.

Comment: you are using both the `%` method and the `{}`.format` method, choose one and stick to it.

Comment: Aye! Thanks @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, it works perfectly fine. I was adding unnecessary braces when not required. That was running into error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of mixing `printf`-style formating and `str.format`, choose one:

[`printf`-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
>>> mytuple = ('new','lets python','python 2.7')
>>> print "%s experience, %s with %s" % mytuple
new experience, lets python with python 2.7
```

[`str.format`](http://%3E%3E%3E%20mytuple%20=%20('new','lets%20python','python%202.7')%20%3E%3E%3E%20print%20%22%25s%20experience,%20%25s%20with%20%25s%22%20%25%20mytuple%20new%20experience,%20lets%20python%20with%20python%202.7%20%3E%3E%3E%20print%20%22%7B0%7D%20experience,%20%7B1%7D%20with%20%7B2%7D%22.format(*mytuple)%20new%20experience,%20lets%20python%20with%20python%202.7):

```
>>> print "{0} experience, {1} with {2}".format(*mytuple)
new experience, lets python with python 2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use format method and asterisk to solve the problem.

please refer to [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for further details

```
>>mytuple=('new','lets python','python 2.7')
>>print "{0} experience, {1} with {2} ".format(*mytuple)
new experience, lets python with python 2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can any one of the method. However the format thing is simpler and you can manage it more easily.

```
>>> a = '{0} HI {1}, Wassup {2}'
>>> a.format('a', 'b', 'c')
'a HI b, Wassup c'
>>> b = ('a' , 'f', 'g')
>>> a.format(*b)
'a HI f, Wassup g'
```

Answer (score 1):

you just mixed up `printf` and `str.format`, you need choose one of them:

```
>>> tuple1 = ("hello", "world", "helloworld")
>>> print("%s, %s, %s" % tuple1)
```

or:

```
>>> tuple1 = ("hello", "world", "helloworld")
>>> print("{}, {}, {}".format(*tuple1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Only need to modify a little：

```
>>> mytuple=('new','lets python','python 2.7')
>>> print "%s experience, %s with %s " %mytuple
new experience, lets python with python 2.7 
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the problem with tuples formatting and came to a solution:

> > > mydate = (9, 1)
> > >       print("The date is ({date[0]}, {date[1]})".format(date=mydate))
> > >       The date is (9, 1)

(It seems the solution is for only some problems, with fixed tuples that we know of.)